# readPort function for serial class in PHP for Windows

Tags: php, arduino, serial-port, read-write

```
function readPort ($count = 0)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED)
        {
            trigger_error("Device must be opened to read it", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->_os === "linux" || $this->_os === "osx")
            {
            // Behavior in OSX isn't to wait for new data to recover, but just grabs what's there!
            // Doesn't always work perfectly for me in OSX
            $content = ""; $i = 0;
            if ($count !== 0)
            {
                do {
                    if ($i > $count) $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, ($count - $i));
                    else $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
            }
            else
            {
                do {
                    $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
            }
            return $content;
        }
        elseif ($this->_os === "windows")
        {
            /* Do nothing : not implented yet */
        }
        trigger_error("Reading serial port is not implemented for Windows", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
```

I have just given a portion of code from Github. These codes are my only point of interest. If you want to see the source, [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/gravataLonga/6c89821b845d15e939a0).

I am searching for how to read serial port data from Arduino to PHP in Windows. After searching so many time I found the code from Github. But where readPort() isn't implemented yet for windows.

Can anyone help me out anyhow ?

Comment: This seems to be [long time problem](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49976) in PHP. Did you try using COM1 or something like that?